# Python Selenium ERROR: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

here is my code to hack password game:
eventually it is saying that password circles(containers) is not interactable, how I can fix this?)

````
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://meduza.io/games/bud-hakerom-igra-meduzy')
xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath
start_button = xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button')
start_button.click()
sleep(4)
driver.switch_to.frame('/embed/cows')
play_button = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/button')
play_button.click()
sleep(1)
first_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[1]')
second_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]')
third_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[3]')
fourth_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[4]')
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        for z in range(10):
            for t in range(10):
                first_container.send_keys(x)
                second_container.send_keys(y)
                third_container.send_keys(z)
                fourth_container.send_keys(t)```
````

Answer (score 1):

ElementNotInteractableException is occured when an element is found, but you can not interact with it. you can using it with actionChains

There are so many reasons of it:

element is not visible / not displayed
element is off screen
element is behind another element or hidden

Find below code, I have tested this with hard coded value :

```
driver.get('https://meduza.io/games/bud-hakerom-igra-meduzy')
xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath
start_button = xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button')
start_button.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame('/embed/cows')
play_button = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/button')
play_button.click()
time.sleep(5)
first_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[1]')
second_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[2]')
third_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[3]')
fourth_container = xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span[4]')


for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        for z in range(10):
            for t in range(10):
                actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
                actionChains.move_to_element(first_container).click().perform()
                actionChains.move_to_element(first_container).send_keys("2").perform()

                actionChains.move_to_element(second_container).click().perform()
                actionChains.move_to_element(second_container).send_keys("3").perform()

                actionChains.move_to_element(third_container).click().perform()
                actionChains.move_to_element(third_container).send_keys("3").perform()

                actionChains.move_to_element(fourth_container).click().perform()
                actionChains.move_to_element(fourth_container).send_keys("3").perform()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```